# How to solve the conflict svn status shows “A+C”

Tags: linux, svn

```
A  +  C application/testbed/filtered.log
>   local edit, incoming delete upon update
M       classes/testmineExport.class.php
```

I am trying to update the filtered.log file At that time I got that error.

Comment: Do you need log file contents to be under version control?

Comment: no, In my local host filtered.log file is not there.But in svn repository it is there, I want to delete from there

Answer (score 1):

The error message (as far as I understand it) says that you've scheduled `filtered.log` for addition but, meanwhile, someone has removed it from the repository. Since you don't really want the file I think you should be able to resolve the conflict this way:

```
svn revert application/testbed/filtered.log
svn update application/testbed/filtered.log
```

In general, you normally want log files out of version control:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*.log" application/testbed
```